# Problem understanding matrix product

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, cross-product

In a textbook I have the following affirmation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0.9 & 0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.8
\end{bmatrix}^n=\frac{1}{0.3}\begin{bmatrix}
0.2 & 0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.1
\end{bmatrix}+\frac{(0.7)^n}{0.3}\begin{bmatrix}
0.1 & -0.1 \\
-0.2 & 0.2
\end{bmatrix}$$

I, however, am unable to reach the same result. Can someone please provide me with a proof of this?

Comment: I do not know why they would have chosen to expand like this.  Usually we would diagonalize the matrix.  Here with $A=\begin{bmatrix}0.9&0.1\\0.2&0.8\end{bmatrix}$ we have that $A=SJS^{-1}$ where $S=\begin{bmatrix}-0.5&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $J=\begin{bmatrix}0.7&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.  We have then $A^n = SJ^nS^{-1}$.  Note that when studying markov chains, we might ask for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A^n$.  Here, see that as $n\to\infty$ you have $J^n\to \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ allowing you to complete the calculation quickly.

Comment: @JMoravitz is done that way so that the values of the matrix can be calculated and it can be multiplied by a 1*2 vector witch represents the start of a Markov chain and the probability of both states can be calculated at a time instant $n$.

Comment: That can be accomplished via the above diagonalization method as well in arguably a more common and routine cookie-cutter approach.